# Classe 'has-error' não desaparece do campo

Tags: angularjs, front-end

Dado um formulário de cliente, valido alguns campos obrigatórios.
Os campos obrigatórios que não forem preenchidos são automaticamente destacados na página para facilitar a vida do usuário. Até aqui 100%. Conforme o usuário enxerga os campos obrigatórios restantes e começa a preencher, automaticamente o destaque (classe has-error do bootstrap) some, normalizando aquele campo.

Acontece que, com apenas um campo do meu formulário, este comportamento não ocorre, ou seja, o campo é destacado no ato da validação, quando o usuário começa a digitar, ele continua destacado como se não estivesse preenchido.

Campo na página (também validado caso seja $dirty e não esteja preenchido):

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6" ng-class="{'has-error': vm.clienteForm.nome.$invalid && vm.clienteForm.nome.$dirty}">
    <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
    <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.cliente.nome" required />
</div>
```

Script que valida todos os campos ao salvar:

```
function salva(cliente) {
    if (vm.clienteForm.$valid) {
        ClienteService.salva(cliente)
            .then(function () {
                $location.path('/clientes');
             });
    } else {
        $('[required]').filter(function () {
            return !this.value.trim();
        }).parent().addClass('has-error');
        MensagensService.mostraMsgErro();
     }
}
```

ps: se eu digito qualquer coisa neste campo e depois apago, aí clico em salvar, após a validação e o destaque, o campo funciona normalmente ao ser digitado (conforme os demais). Logo, ele só não funciona quando a primeira coisa que eu faço é clicar no botão salvar, com aquele campo ainda virgem/intacto ($pristine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O angular está dando conflito com o jquery

```
$('[required]').filter(function () {
        return !this.value.trim();
    }).parent().addClass('has-error');
```

Aconselho você colocar uma validação de formulário setando no controller se ele está valido ou não(conforme exemplo abaixo). Com esta validação, acredito que o $dirty não será mais necessário.

```js
angular
    .module('myApp', [])
    .controller('MyController', MyController);

function MyController(){
 var vm = this;
 vm.salva = salva;

function salva(cliente) {
  
    if (vm.clienteForm.$valid) {
      vm.formInvalido = false;  
      // Seu service
    } else {
        vm.formInvalido = true;
        // Seu service
     }
}
  };
```

```css
div.has-error{color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController as vm">
<form name="vm.clienteForm">
  <div class="form-group col-md-6" ng-class="{'has-error': vm.clienteForm.nome.$invalid && vm.formInvalido}">
    <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
    <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.cliente.nome" required />
</div>
    
    <button ng-click="vm.salva(vm.cliente)">Salvar</button>
</div>
  </form>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ótima abordagem! Eu realmente não estava muito feliz com a filtragem nos campos obrigatórios com jQuery. Apenas tive que adaptar o ng-class do input, pois também considero $dirty.

Segue:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6" ng-class="{'has-error': vm.clienteForm.nome.$invalid && (vm.clienteForm.nome.$dirty || vm.formInvalido)}">
    <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
    <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.cliente.nome" required />
</div>
```

ps: O $dirty ainda se faz necessário pois, caso o usuário digite algo, apague o que digitou e saia do campo, o destaque já é aplicado.